# Write to stdin of python multiprocessing.Process

Tags: python, linux, multithreading

I need to write data to a Process I've created. For various reasons, it *has* to be a `multiprocessing.Process`. Let's say that this Process does something like run `apt upgrade`, and will then be prompted for a [Y/n] from the user. What is the best way to send a Y or n? I've done a lot of searching and found quite a few half-answers about duplicating stdin, but I haven't been able to come up with a full solution. Here's a minimal example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import sys
import multiprocessing

e = multiprocessing.Event()

def get_input():
    try:
        x = input("Go ahead - type something\n")
        print("typed " + x)
    finally:
        e.set()

# 1. Here it seems we should replace stdin?

multiprocessing.Process(target=get_input).start()

# 2. Here I want to write to stdin such that Process started above receives input

e.wait()
```

Of course, this dies immediately because the stdin used by input is closed and just returns an EOF. How can I override stdin to take input from a file or some kind of local buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution that works for me. Editing the code sample above:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import multiprocessing
import sys

def get_input(newstdin, done):
    sys.stdin = newstdin # replace stdin

    try:
        x = input("Go ahead - type something\n")
        print("typed " + x)
    finally:
        done.set()

# This class will pretend to be stdin for my process
class FakeStdin(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.input = multiprocessing.Queue()

    def readline(self):
        output = self.input.get(timeout=10)
        return output or ''

    def write(self, message):
        self.input.put(message)

done = multiprocessing.Event()
newstdin = FakeStdin()

multiprocessing.Process(target=get_input, args=(newstdin, done)).start()

newstdin.write("test string") # write to the fake stdin

done.wait()
```

Basically, I create a fake stdin to give to me process which sets sys.stdin. this fake stdin only needs to implement `readline` to duck-type my usage of stdin here. In `readline`, I wait for input using a `Queue`, which I set with a method I call `write`.